# Comparing two hash-maps and printing intersections

Tags: java, hashmap, comparison

I have two hash maps: one contains an Integer key and String value.

The other contains an Integer key and float value.

## Code

```
Map<Integer,String> mapA = new HashMap<>();
mapA.put(1, "AS");
mapA.put(2, "Wf");

Map<Integer,Float> mapB = new HashMap<>();
mapB.put(2, 5.0f);
mapB.put(3, 9.0f);
```

My question is how to compare the two hash maps using the integer key value? I want to print the bitmap value when the key values are the same.

Comment: I don't know what the second part is supposed to do but it definitely wouldn't compile.

Comment: Are your keys supposed to be numbers? because you seem to be using strings

Comment: actually i am using bitmap in my  android application.now i change my code in simple format.

Comment: Do you want the intersection of the two keysets?

Comment: yes..i want float value.

Comment: If you want float value, you might fix your question to specify "float" instead of "bitmap value".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes i got solution...

```
 if(mapB.containsKey(position)){
          Log.e("bucky",mapB.get(position));}
```

position means integer value.

Answer (score 2):

You can just iterate on the keys of `mapA` and check if it is present in `mapB` then add the value to a third `mapC` for example.

```
Map<String, float> mapC = new HashMap<String, float>();

for (Integer key : mapA.keySet()) {
    if (mapB.containsKey(key)) {
        mapC.put(mapA.get(key), mapB.get(key));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare keys in two map by using mapB iterator.

```
Iterator<Entry<Integer, Float>> iterator = mapB.entrySet().iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        Entry<Integer, Float> entry = iterator.next();
        Integer integer = entry.getKey();
        if(mapA.containsKey(integer)) {
            System.out.println("Float Value : " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to modify `mapB`, then the solution is as simple as `mapB.keySet().retainAll(mapA.keySet());`.

This will only leave those entries in `mapB` that have a corresponding key in `mapA`, because the set returned by `keySet()` is backed by the map itself, any changes made to it will be reflected to the map.

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8 Streams API:

```
Map<Integer, Object> matchInBothMaps = mapA
                                            .entrySet()
                                            .stream() 
                                            .filter(map -> mapB.containsKey(map.getKey())) 
                                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(map -> map.getKey(), 
                                                                      map -> map.getValue()));
        
System.out.println(matchInBothMaps);
```